# Can Pages '09 create a list inside a list?

Tags: macos, pages, iwork

Is there a way to create a "sublist" inside a list item from an outer list in Pages '09?

More specifically, I want to do this:

Example made with HTML (should look like [this](http://d.pr/i/LaUB)):

```
<ol start="1">
  <li>First category</li>
  <li>Second category:
    <br>
    Here is a text. And a list:
    <ul>
      <li>Point</li>
      <li>Another point</li>
    </ul>
    Proceed with text. Perfect.
  </li>
  <li>Third category</li>
</ol>
```

Here's a screenshot of Pages where I'm trying to do this.

[image]

Comment: BTW: I made the new line after 'Two' with [ctrl]+[Enter].

Comment: Excellent edit to clarify the case here. I've a sneaking suspicion you'll need to modify styles to get an indented body style that happens to be the same amount of indent as the `- Two:` item with no space before or after, but I'll have a look later to see if this is possible without resorting to custom styles that would be fragile if you changed the level of indent.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Yes, changing the color is *cheating* and it's not an elegant solution...

In order to change the icon color, you need to open the inspector
 <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and go to *T → List → Bullets & Numbering*

Comment: You're right. It's possible to make lists in Pages as I made them with HTML before. I updated my question to explain exactly what I wanted to do.